# I'm getting the exception "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException" even though control is available

Tags: unit-tests, c#, coded-ui-tests

As the title says i'm getting this exception when running my coded U.I Test. Currently i've researched and i cant pin point on whether this is an issue with IE9 or with my program or even VS itself.

1. I have debugged my program bringing it to the same point that it failed before and it did not fail but continued and didnt receive the error.
   (note i didn't run this from the beginning since it would of taken over an hr again).
2. I'm currently running VS 2013 Ultimate
3. The Test is running on browser IE9 v 9.08112
4. The test usually bombs out as its in the middle after an 1hr or so.  So i dont know if the lenght of this has an issue.
5. Here is my stack trace:

> Test method verifyEachCarouselOnLetter threw exception:  The Internet
>   Explorer window is not available.
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.IEWebControlElement.EnsureValidTopWindow()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.BrowserHtmlNode.EnsureValid()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.BrowserHtmlNode.get_HtmlElementNode()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.BrowserHtmlNode.get_Name()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UIMap.UIMapUtil.FillPropertyFromUIElement(UIObject
>   obj, IUITechnologyElement element)  at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UIMap.UIMapUtil.FromUIElement(IUITechnologyElement
>   element, UIObject obj)at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UIMap.UIMapUtil.FromUIElement(IUITechnologyElement
>   element)at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.GetUITestControlString(UITestControl
>   control)at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.EnsureValid(Boolean
>   waitForReady, Boolean refetch) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyValuePrivate(String
>   propertyName)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyPrivate(String
>   propertyName)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl+<>c__DisplayClass3b.b__3a()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod(Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String
>   propertyName)at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlHyperlink.get_Target()The
>   Internet Explorer window is not available. Ignoring exception as
>   PlaybackErrorOption.Retry was chosen

Can someone point me in the right direction as too what this issue might be since i'm currently clueless.  I dont really have a clue on where to start since i already debugged this and could not recreate it and because my test will take over hrs to run and i don't want this to continue to happen without the test finishing.

Comment: Try troubleshooting guidelines at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tapas_sahoos_blog/archive/2011/11/07/troubleshooting-record-and-playback-issues-in-coded-ui-test.aspx I'd suggest to enable logs as well, instructions are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/11/29/how-to-enable-tracing-for-ui-test-components.aspx

Comment: Why does your test run an hour? How do you debug if an issue arises after an hour, change the code, start test, wait an hour, see your change did not work and repeat? Really you should split up your tests in the smallest chunks possible, so that the tests run quickly after each other.

Answer (score 1):

> The Internet Explorer window is not available

This is your error, possible causes:

- Window is renamed to something else along the way?
- Window is closed by a test step
- Internet Explorer crashed? IE is not known for its stability, certainly not version 9. Check the Windows application logs.
- Memory leaks: Maybe running a single test for an hour in it is not a good idea. Do your users also use it for an hour? If so maybe check for memory leaks in the client-side code. I have had a JavaScript browser application using absurd amounts (in the GigaBytes) of memory in IE.

You could try to record the test run to a video and check the steps in the playback: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286596.aspx